# Best way to use an object in Python?

Tags: python

Which is best?

**Method 1**

```
object = Object()
object.method()
```

**Method 2**

```
Object().method()
```

This is for use within another class, so I could ether setup all the objects needed as properties for that class (first method) or just access them using the second method?

What are the reasons (if any) for using each method.

Comment: Use whatever is most readable to you. The latter uses 2 fewer opcodes  in the compiled bytecode, but that is not going to matter unless you are doing this is a loop with a million iterations.

Comment: If you're making an object but disregarding its state, you might be doing something wrong.

Comment: I have to agree with @WaleedKhan. What does `method()` do, and why is it an instance method of some object you're going to immediately discard instead of a normal function?

Comment: There will only be one of any object at a time for what I'm doing if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first method is the usual way. Since the instantiated object is bound to a variable, it can be used afterwards. Btw, you probably mean object.method(), not object.method (parentheses are used to actually call the method).

Method 2 does not bind the instance, so it is no longer addressable and may be garbage collected later on. Use method 2 only if you don't have to use the instance after calling the method.

Comment: "may be garbage collected later on" is misleading. At least in cPython, it *will* be removed immediately without needing garbage collection because its reference count is 0.

Comment: @Wooble -- While you're right, I'm not sure that other python implementations do this the same way.  We need to be careful treating `cPython` as the *only* python.  I certainly see other implementations gaining traction ...

Comment: If I access the object in multiple lines, but use method 2 kind of like [Class::method()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) in PHP, would that be ok? I won't be changing any of the values in the object.

Comment: If you do that, you actually instantiate it multiple times. Even if it works with the kind of class you use, it has some probably useless overhead. I don't know PHP, but I cannot see the advantage of method 2 except if the class is specifically designed this way, which is rarely the case.

Answer (score 1):

The first form maintains a binding to the created object.  The latter creates a new object with each call.  I think that most people would prefer the former.